# How to increase the track height of a slider in material design 3

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui, material-design-3

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SliderWithCustomTrackAndThumb() {
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()
    val colors = SliderDefaults.colors(thumbColor = Color.Red, activeTrackColor = Color.Red)
    Column {
        Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())
        Slider(
            modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
            value = sliderPosition,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
            valueRange = 0f..100f,
            onValueChangeFinished = {
                // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
                // viewModel.updateSelectedSliderValue(sliderPosition)
            },
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            thumb = {
                SliderDefaults.Thumb(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    colors = colors
                )
            },
            track = { sliderPositions ->
                SliderDefaults.Track(
                    colors = colors,
                    sliderPositions = sliderPositions
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The above composable function creates a sample slider with a custom thumb size. I want to increase the size of the track. how can I do that?

Comment: You can't do it with default M2 or M3 Slider. You can check out this library https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Colorful-Sliders

Answer (score 3):

while you can't change the size size of the track set in the `SlideDefaults.Track()`component, you can always provide your own track implementation by copying the code from the `SliderDefaults` and change the track size there.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase or decrease the size of the track and thumb using scale modifiers. This is how I do it:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Slider() {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
        value = 0.5f,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onValueChange = { value: Float -> },
        valueRange = 0f..1f,
        track = { sliderPositions ->
            SliderDefaults.Track(
                modifier = Modifier.scale(scaleX = 1f, scaleY = 0.5f),
                sliderPositions = sliderPositions
            )
        },
        thumb = {
            SliderDefaults.Thumb(
                modifier = Modifier.scale(scaleX = 0.5f, scaleY = 0.5f),
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
            )
        }
    )
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOp2w.png)